# How to add button to ActionBarSherlock for starting an activity?

Tags: android

I am using ABS(ActionBarSherlock) in my project.
I want to add a button to the ABS which would start an activity or close the activity if its already running.
How can I do so?

Comment: Just in case you are starting a new project and you don't know it, but you don't need anymore the ABS, the last support packages contains an implementation of the actionbar compatible with older version of Android

Answer (score 0):

Since ActionBarSherlock behaves like the original implementation of the ActionBar, you can follow the official documentation to achieve this. It's located [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html).

The easiest way is using an `XML` file.

Create `res/menu/mymenu.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```